# Java File Path Best Practice

Tags: java

If operating system is Windows, which one given below is a best approach of coding in Java?

1)

```
 String f = "some\\path\\file.ext";
```

2)

```
 String f = "some/path/file.ext";
```

3)

```
  String f = "some"+File.separator+"path"+File.separator+"file.ext";
```

4)

```
 String f = new StringBuilder("some").append(File.separator).append("path").append(File.separator).append("file.ext").toString();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Given the comments, I should clarify. This definitely depends on context. What are you trying to do? If you're trying to create a file path in the "native" operating system format, I would use option 5, using [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

```
File f = new File("some");
f = new File(f, "path");
f = new File(f, "file.ext");
```

Or better, put this logic into a method:

```
public static File newFile(String root, String... parts) {
    // TODO: Check that nothing's null (root, parts, each element of parts)
    File ret = new File(root);
    for (String part : parts) {
        ret = new File(ret, part);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
File f = SomeUtilityClass.newFile("some", "path", "file.ext");
```

(It's possible that this exists somewhere in recent JREs, but if so I don't know where.)

If you only need something that will work for `FileInputStream` etc, then I *might* just hard-code the forward-slashes, for two reasons:

- They're easier to read than the backslashes
- They'll work on other operating systems too

Either way, I would probably still create a `File`, as it gives clearer meaning to the value. Most IO APIs in Java accept a `File` where appropriate - and it makes it obvious to all the code surrounding it that this *is* a file path. So you could use:

```
File file = new FIle("some/path/file.ext");
```

... and that would still work on Windows. You could then use `File.getCanonicalFile` to get a canonical representation, which would have backslashes rather than forward slashes, if you wanted.

Comment: Really..!? Could you elloborate a bit ? Doesn't seem more expensive with two more new File instance ?

Comment: @Aubin: In what way is it "very painful"? And where does the question mention anything about user input?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: Yes, it creates a few more objects. That's incredibly unlikely to be significant unless your program spends most of its time working out file paths.

Comment: It might be technically the safest way to do this but (with the method approach) you have to balance that up with the fact you're adding a lot of bloat to do something very simple and everywhere you use this, you're adding a dependency, which reduces portability and reuse. For most things, using '/' is fine but I would always put file paths in a config file anyway and never hard-code them.

Comment: @ac7web: What dependency is being added? To a utility class? Surely that *increases* reuse (the same code can be reused everywhere), and constructing the right `File` object *increases* portability (it will do the right thing on every OS).

Comment: @JonSkeet yes the utility class. Problem is, people tend to bloat their code with these 'utility' classes all the time and create dependency webs. Then when you want to take a module out and reuse it in another project, you end up pulling a whole load of stuff you don't need with it. It gets interesting when that new project also has it's own utility classes that do the same thing.... smelly code.

Comment: @ac7web: So you'd rather repeat similar code umpteen in every class that needs to do it? No thanks. Of course it's nicer when a single utility *library* has everything you need - and Guava normally fills that hole for me. But when it doesn't, I'm absolutely fine with extracting commonly-used code into its own class.

Comment: While this is the "safest" way, I don't like the approach. (1) You often want paths in variables, from input or from property files and (2) the code takes longer to read than some of the alternatives.

Comment: @Vegard: It does depend on the context. But the context of the question was clearly one where the OP has the three sections separately.

Answer (score 3):

[Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is right but I want to say that Microsoft impose the use of `\` only in command interpreter. Every where in the API you can use `/`.

So you can use `String f = "some/path/file.ext";` everywhere but in `ProcessBuilder` if the launched program is `cmd.exe`.

To convert paths, I use `String.replaceAll( "\\\\", "/" );`

Comment: It's possible that you may pass the file path into other programs which are overly sensitive, too. (e.g. things that split on `\\` to find the files.)

Comment: Bad programming: in C/C++ under Windows, I use /, never \, but I agree with you it's a risk

Answer (score 1):

Paths are often stored in properties files, for most applications I have worked with, we have always used alternative 2.

One of the reasons for this is that it looks similar between windows and linux.

/path or C:/path

it is also the cleanest and most readable alternative.