# platform independent way to get current java executable path and filename

Tags: java, processbuilder

I need to execute a java application using `ProcessBuilder`.   I also need to use the same java executable in the called process that is being used by the calling application.

Is there a platform independent way to retrieve the current java executable path and file name?

I've seen some code snippets similar to this:

```
public static boolean isWindows() {
    return (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") >= 0);
}

public static String getJavaExecutablePath() {

    String executable = "java";
    if (isWindows()) {
       executable = executable + ".exe";
    }
    File path = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"), "/bin/" + executable);
    return path.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

The above code will probably need to be improved to use `File.separator`.

Is the above all that is required, or is there something else to consider, for example case sensitivity?

Ideally, there would be a library available for getting the OS path, but that is probably a question for a different forum.

Answer (score 1):

First, the most important thing for your requirement is ***System.getProperty("java.home")***, you've got it already.

Secondly, don't worry about case sensitivity, the path '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java' always be in lower case in every java release, and there are already many other projects depend on this.

Last thing, you don't have to use a '/' or '\' to build the absolute path, consider this:

```java
File path = new File(new File(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin"), executable);
```

As you mentioned the *File.separator* did similar thing, but that is talking about a string, and *File* talks about file.

[Here is a discussion about File path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632283/625834)